# Previous slide and auto play Jquery slider,

Tags: javascript, jquery

I`m trying to figure out how to make a jquery slider, I got 2 main problems.

[LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vo690an8/4/)

PROBLEM 1
Previous slide. 
Its going to the previous slide, but after clickCount == slider.length, it just disapears.

```
//previous

$("#previous").click(function(){
     if(clickCount < slider.length)
           slider.eq(clickCount--).hide();

     if(clickCount == slider.length)
         clickCount = 0;
      slider.eq(clickCount).show();
 }) ;
```

PROBLEM 2
Auto Play
My auto-play logic is not working...

```
//autoplay


$(document).ready(function(){
var presentSlide = 0

     if(presentSlide < slider.length)
           slider.eq(presentSlide++).fadeOut(600);
     if(presentSlide == slider.length)
         presentSlide = 0;
      slider.eq(clickCount).fadeIn(600);
 }) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:

You have to check `clickCount` different than the `next`button:

```
$("#previous").click(function(){
     if(clickCount >= 0) 
           slider.eq(clickCount--).hide();              
     if(clickCount < 0)
         clickCount = slider.length-1;
      slider.eq(clickCount).show();
 }) ;
```

Problem 2:

For the auto-play, why don't you just `click` the `next` button every X seconds?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
             $("#next").click();
         },5000);  //every 5000 ms (5 seconds)
 }) ;
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vo690an8/5/)